# Map multiple excel cells into xml

Tags: xml, excel

I'll try to explain my problem best way (sorry for my ENglish).

I've an excel file structured in this way.

Column1 Column2 Column3  ... ColumnN
1        Mario   Luigi
2        Peach   Wario
.
.
.

I've a XML Schema (.xds) to map that spreadsheet.
The schema is:

```
<root id="x">
  <Column1> *something*</Column1>
  <Column2> *something*</Column2>
  *...and so on...*
</root>
```

When I map the excel file whit XML Schema I can only ONE cell to ONE xml element. So I can map a cell of Column1 with the element Column1 into XML Schema. I hope this is clear.
But I want to map MULTIPLE cells for the element Column1 in the XML Schema.
In other words, I want to recive multiple   when I export XML file from Excel (one for every row).

What I should expect *mapping multiple cells*

```
<root id="1">
<Column1> 1</Column1>
  <Column2> Mario</Column2>
  *...and so on...*
</root>

<root id="2">
  <Column1> 1</Column1>
  <Column2> Peach</Column2>
  *...and so on...*
</root>
```

What I get mapping *ONLY ONE* cells

```
<root id="1">
  <Column1> 1</Column1>
  <Column2> Mario</Column2>
  *...and so on...*
</root>
```

I hope my question is clear: how I can map multiple cells for one element of my XML Scheme?

Thanks.

Comment: Which tool are you using? It's not clear

Comment: @RiccardoCossu Built in excel mapping

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert the XLS file into a CSV one and then using a python script, convert the CSV file into an XML one.
Check this code [CSV to XML](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577423-convert-csv-to-xml/)

Comment: @user3864091 i've added the link into my previous reply

Answer (score 0):

Or you could simply write a text file with your xml code, and then save it with the desired extention. For example

```
Dim fsT As Object
Set fsT = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
fsT.Type = 2                ' Specifies stream type - save text data.
fsT.Charset = "utf-8"       ' Specifies charset For the source text data.
fsT.lineseparator = 10      ' Pushes enter when a line is finished
fsT.Open

fsT.WriteText <root id="1">, 1
fsT.WriteText <Column1> 1</Column1>, 1 ' you can substitute a Cell.Column to this "1"
fsT.WriteText     <Column2> Mario</Column2>, 1 ' same here, you can give input by a cell for example
fsT.WriteText     *...and so on...* , 1
fsT.WriteText </root>, 1

' Do it how many times you want then...

fsT.SaveToFile YourFileName, 2 ' Saves (and overwrites) data
fsT.Close
Set fsT = Nothing
```